# NullReferenceException when inheriting from MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I working on a unity project and I have a script which works perfectly without inheriting from MonoBehaviour. I need to inherit this script from MonoBehaviour to adjust a public variable with the inspector and when I do I get NullReferenceException from public values who where handled correctly in the script without inheriting from MonoBehaviour.

I know it might seem unclear but does anyone have an idea on what's going on and how to fix it ?

[image: Screenshot of GUIDisplay instance in Unity editor]

The first element InputField is the only public element I need to bind to script, the others variables worked fine without :MonoBehaviour. Can I make them ignore it ?

Comment: How about you show us this problematic script?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, my script was instantiated by another script causing a lot of trouble noting related to MonoBehavior directly. 
I'm sorry for my silly question.